# Injector design - LOX vs nitrous oxide

Tags: engine-design, liquid-fuel, lox, oxidizer, injector

What will be the main design differences between using liquid oxygen and liquid nitrous oxide as oxidizer in a bi-propellant rocket engine? What liquid/gas properties (vapor pressure etc.) play the biggest role in injector design?

When considering for example an impinging injector - how does LOX design need to change for nitrous oxide when considering same fuel (like RP-1, ethanol etc.)?